Kafka external client receives other name than in ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
On a local network, I have a broker at cgw.local and a client at rpi.local, connected to the same switch. No matter what I put into kafka.advertised.listeners: PLAINTEXT://cgw.local:9092 or PLAINTEXT://20.5.28.284:9092, or whether the (Python's) client BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS is ['cgw.local'] or ['20.5.28.284:9092'], after a successfull subscription the client complaints:
WARNING:kafka.conn:DNS lookup failed for cgw:9092, exception was [Errno -2] Name or service not known. Is your advertised.listeners (called advertised.host.name before Kafka 9) correct and resolvable?

and does not download any messages. It looks for cgw which does not exist, what exists is cgw.local or (dynamic) 20.5.28.284.
Here are the server properties:
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
broker.id=0
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
kafka.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
kafka.advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://cgw.local:9092 # or 20.5.28.284:9092

There is no docker involved, Kafka runs directly on cgw.local.

Why are you combining uppercase and lowercase values in the properties? If you're not using containers, that's not valid

@OneCricketeer It's a test installation. I just followed the first option in the tutorial.

Sorry, which tutorial? By setting kafka.listeners to localhost, you're explicitly saying not to allow external connections. Are you restarting the broker after each file change? Also, if DNS is failing, you'll need to consult your DNS server, not the Kafka settings. E.g ping cgw is going to fail also

@OneCricketeer One source said that you need PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 for external clients, another said that this property is only for internal clients so I changed it back to localhost:9092. In both cases, external clients see a modified version of kafka.advertised.listeners despite what the tutorials say. The DNS is not failing, the server is supposed to be cgw.local and not cgw.

I use sudo systemctl restart kafka after any changes to the configuration.

Listeners is for all connections. kafka.advertised.listeners is not a valid broker config. Again, what tutorial are you using?
